# How to write expression inside ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have to put an expression inside ng-if which should be evaluated and my content is displayed based on its value. Currently my code is

```
<a ng-if="abc.status===failure" href="http://localhost:3000/abc/abc">image</a>
```

Currently it is never getting displayed. Surprisingly syntax of double quotes works if I just want to test if the value is null

```
<a ng-if="value" href="http://localhost:3000/abc/abc">{{image}}</a>
```

How do I evaluate abc.status===failure and assign the result to ng-if

Comment: please, show your controller code. `ng-if` accepts expressions, maybe you should write like this: `<a ng-if="abc.status === 'failure'">...`. And one more note: it's a bad practice to write expressions in HTML, had better move it into controller

Comment: worked with failure enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap `failure` in quote, change:

```
<a ng-if="abc.status===failure" href="http://localhost:3000/abc/abc">image</a>
```

to

```
<a ng-if="abc.status==='failure'"
href="http://localhost:3000/abc/abc">image</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Evaluated based on the type of variable.

1. For the numbers - ng-if="status===1"
2. For the strings - ng-if="status==='str'"

Refer: 
Working sample is avail in "http://jsfiddle.net/Boopathi_Sakthivel/v75Nk/

```
 <div ng-controller = "mycontroller" >
        <a ng-if="status===1"
href="http://localhost:3000/abc/abc">status</a>
        <a ng-if="statusStr==='failure'"
href="http://localhost:3000/abc/abc">statusStr</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a proof in plunker http://plnkr.co/xbsrp0mUsAMCRMJrV0pc that `ng-if` accepts expression. I believe you have a syntax error or something like this. Try to enclose `'failure'` in single quotes and recheck your variable names